# Adding Action bar to Default Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme, android-datepicker

I am trying to add an action bar to my application. Below is a screen shot of my current application UI.

[image]

I am using a default theme so the action bar won't get displayed. So i am using a theme with action bar. When i use the theme, my UI gets messed up. The date picker changes its style.  Below is an example, how the action bar is displayed.

[image]

Below is the xml code which contains action bar items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"

    android:title="Search"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>


<!-- Refresh -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"

    android:title="Refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<!-- Help -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_help"

    android:title="Help"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>

<!-- Check for updates -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_check_updates"

    android:title="Check for Updates"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Below is the theme am using in the application make the action bar visible.

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Is there anyway to add the action bar to my default theme?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are seeing is the correct behavior, you use a different theme so things look different.

Also using `Theme.Holo` is an old theme, you should be using the `Theme.Material` as all examples you will find will be using that theme/UI elements from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using `Theme.Holo.Light`, this is giving you a light background. You can try `@android:style/Theme.Material`, as seen [here(https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html), but that requires Api 21. Otherwise you can try:

```
<style name="CustomDarkTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid</item>
</style>
```